# Seam component reuse - outjected @DataModel variable conflict

Tags: components, seam, reusability, datamodel

I need your suggestions as usual ;)

In my Seam app, there's a JSF view page processing 3 similar types of data, so I wrote a Seam component and would like to reuse it three times. The problem is, the component outjects some data used by the view into @DataModel variable. Now, is there a clever way to variate three conflicting variable names without using inheritance etc? If not, what kind of other approach would you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest don't use outjection and use inheritance and just getters to access variable.

ie: #{bean1.var} #{bean2.var} #{bean3.var}